# Shell script to loop through different directories and search for a specific html tag

Tags: bash, shell

There is a directory structure of the below kind:

```
                  services (directory)
         |                                           |            
 serviceui (directory)                     serviceui1 (directory)
         |                                           |
 service1 (directory)                      service2 (directory)
         |                                           |
 frontend                                  frontend
         |                                           |
           Have different files and each file has 
           a html tag with different tags.
           For example, a sample file may contain
             <Id>CheckUser</Id>
             <Id1> bbb </Id1>
             <Id2> drer </Id2>
```

I am trying to write a bash shell script that loops through all the directories and different files in frontend directory to look for the serviceId html tag and find out how many serviceIds have the content "CheckUser"
in it.

This is the first time I am working with bash scripts. Any heads up on this would be really very helpful.

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1):

How 'bout `grep -r -c '<Id>CheckUser</Id>' *` ?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16480086)

Comment: Actually, it was intended to be an answer.  As in,"How 'bout you try this?"  Perhaps I phrased it badly, but do you see any reason that it would not work?

Comment: Adding some explanation can really improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: I like to rip on regex as much as everyone else, but it doesn't appear to me that properly parsing HTML is required in this context. This answer may not be foolproof, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use grep recursively:

```
grep -Fsrc '<Id>CheckUser</Id>' "services (directory)" |awk -F: '$NF > 0'
```

This tells grep to search for the given query as plain text (`-F`, which is much faster than using a regex), ignore errors like parsing a directory as a file (`-s`), parse recursively (`-r`), and count the number of lines containing the pattern for each file examined.

The awk command suppresses any line in which the count is zero.  `-F:` sets the field delimiter to colon and `$NF` refers to the value of the last field (`NF` is the number of fields, `$NF` is the value of field number `NF`).  Awk is a list of conditions; this code is shorthand for `$NF > 0 { print $0 }` since that particular action is the default when an action is not given.  This is optional (you might want to see all of the zeros).

**Notes:**

Your question was hard to read.  I've over-corrected and assumed the target directory name is literally `services (directory)` but you could use any path, even `.` for your current location.

This assumes you're not really using HTML or XML.  It will fail to find multi-line instances like this:

```html
<Id>
  CheckUser
</Id>
```

If that is a concern, you really need code that understands XML structure.  Otherwise you'd need some rather ugly hacks like collapsing all whitespace and parsing the file as a single-line string.